# Remove empty spaces and period

Tags: regex

I cannot get this regex to work:

```
"4.  182 ex" (number, period, 2 blank spaces, 3 numbers, blank space, 2 characters"
```

The regex syntax should return "4182" and remove period, blank spaces, and characters.

Can you help me please?

EDIT!!!

Thanks everyone but I missed the key question:

a) the regex shall **only** find the value (4182) when the same line contains a specific text for example "magic", so for example:

"Magic     4.  182 ex"

b) the regex shall "only" find the value (4182) when the table contains a specific text for example "Magic":

"Magic    4.   182 ex

Lisefeo  2.   123 fg

Nioos    3.   124 df"

specific text = exact match or contains those charachters

My regex that I've tried so far but does it work for a whole table (not just a line) ?

(Magic.*?(\d).\s\s(\d{3})\s\w\w)

Comment: `this regex` -- which regex?

Comment: Please indicate which language you're using, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove all characters that are not digit:

Perl:

```
$string =~  s/\D+//g;
```

or
php:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\D+/', '', $string);
```

According to your updated question, you could do:

```
$string =~ s/^Magic(\d+)\.  (\d{3})\b.*$/$1$2/
```

or, with php:

```
$string = preg_replace('/^Magic(\d+)\.  (\d{3})\b.*$/', '$1$2', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

For it to match exactly what you said, use:

```
(\d)\.\s\s(\d{3})\s\w\w
```

You'll get it in two groups, first digit and second digit group.

[RegEx101 exmple](http://regex101.com/r/wB2lF6)

Regards.

Comment: thanks it captures 1st group and 2nd group but how can these groups be merged? I only want "4182" as 1 group...

Answer (score 0):

```
^([\d]+)\.[\s]+([\d]+)[\s]..
```

Tested with perl:

```
> echo "4. 182 ex" | perl -lne 'print $1,$2 if(/^([\d]+)\.[\s]+([\d]+)[\s]../)'
4182
```